# Enter/Return key not moving to new line in textarea

Tags: html, css

I seem to have lost the default textarea behavior when pressing the enter/return key. I want that key press to move the cursor to the next line, but it just inserts a couple of spaces instead. Must be something in my css rules, but I don't know what it is.

```css
button, input, textarea, select {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d4d4d4;
    background: #fff;
}
textarea {
    height: 8em;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="Textarea1" placeholder="Text area"></textarea>
```

Comment: seems ok to me in chrome on a mac

Comment: What browser are you using? Is there any css rules being inherited?

Comment: @bdkopen No, you can see the embedded snippet above to see there are no css rules being inherited. I'm using Safari on a Mac.

Comment: @JROB looks like `white-space: nowrap` - what's the point of that in the textarea?

Comment: Believe this is a client side issue.

Comment: @ChaniquaCrook pointed out "it only works in Chrome and Edge on PC. Firefox only enters one space."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `white-space: nowrap;` on line 14.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: I found that the default behavior of a textarea is `white-space: pre;`, so I updated my CSS rules as follows, and it works fine now:

```css
button, input, textarea, select {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d4d4d4;
    background: #fff;
}
textarea {
    height: 8em;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="Textarea1" placeholder="Text area"></textarea>
```